# Hill Climbing Algorithm for finding Maxima in MATALB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am trying to make a program in MATLAB in which we have to find the maxima.
The algorithm which I am using is compare the given point with two adjacent points.
If the next point is greater than the present , iterate in positive direction.
If the next point is smaller than the present, iterate in the negative direction.
If the previous point and the next point are less than the present, maxima reached.

I have made a while loop with flag variable.But it is not able to detect the maxima.

I intialize x to some number intially (say x = 0)
The function 'f(x) = -x^2 -3;'
The variable 'xint ' is the interval which is set to say 0.1.
The variable 'i' is just to keep a count.

```
clc
clear all

syms x

f(x) = -x^2+3;
max = 0;
x = 0;
xint = 0.1;
flag =1;

while(flag ==1)
    fprintf('\ninside while\n')
        if(f(x+xint)> f(x))
              x = x + xint;
              fprintf('inside first: Value of x is set to = %f, where function value is %f', x, f(x));

       elseif(f(x+xint) < f(x))
               x = x-xint;
               fprintf('inside second: Value of x is set to = %f, where function value is %f', x, f(x)); 

       else if(f(x-xint)<f(x) & f(x+xint) < f(x))
              disp('Max detected')
              max = x;
              flag =0;
       end
       i = i+1;
 end
```

Any help will be of use to me.

Thank You very much.

Anupam

Input :
f(x) = -x^2 +3;

Output:
The program does not enter into the third else if statement.And thus while loop keeps running.

Comment: What is your data? Give an example and the output of it, then we would be able to understand what you mean. The explanation is quite confusing

Comment: matalb ? you will find more answers with a right title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a condition for the `else` clause. Additionally, if you were to make the `else` into an `elseif` it was be unreachable as the condition you wrote there can I be true when the condition you have for the previous `elseif` is true, but in a if-elseif statements only one clause gets executed every time.

Change the condition of the `elseif` and get to of the condition for the `else`:

```
   elseif(f(x-xint) > f(x))
           x = x-xint;
           fprintf('inside second: Value of x is set to = %f, where function value is %f', x, f(x)); 

   else
          disp('Max detected')
          max = x;
          flag =0;
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming xint is a positive value and your function is second degree polinomial with negative constant `(i.e. y = a*x^2+b where a < 0)`, then:

```
if f(x+xint) > f(x) % go to right.
     x1 = x+xint; 
else                     %  go to left
     x1 = x
     xint = -xint;
 end

 while f(x1) > f(x1+xint)
      x1 = x1+xint;
 end
```

Here x1 is maxima or something very close to it.